# Tensorflow estimator exporter when training data is from tfrecords and inference is from raw data

Tags: tensorflow

**Background**

0) I'm working on an NLP model that I would like to export

1) I have training data in the form of tfRecords

2) I would like to export my model and host it on a flask app, so the data that comes in is raw text

3) I handle all my pre-processing (tokenization and such) as part of my tensorflow graph

**Question**

1) Given the fact that I do the data loading (tf.Dataset creation, and pre-processing) as part of tensorflow graph, would the raw text that comes in break the process? (specifically in the tf.Dataset creation step)

2) Would it make more sense to just load in raw text instead of tf.Dataset data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NVM, I completely forgot that you want to have an `input_function` which you feed datasets through, and a `serving_input_function` which accepts raw data